# How to install KDE on Debian 6?

Tags: kde, xfce, desktop-environment

I have GNOME 2.30.2 that came with my default Debian installation. I have the following Debian installation:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.5
Codename:       squeeze
```

I want to install some other desktop environment. What is the procedure for installing KDE or Xfce on Debian 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aptitude install kde-desktop should do the trick

http://pkg-kde.alioth.debian.org/kde3.html

and if I am correct aptitude install xfce-desktop would do this for xfce.

Comment: It is not possible to update GNOME to latest version in Debian 6. It breaks things. I hope upgrading to KDE has no such issue. Besides that article you pointed out is for Debian 5.

Comment: try also: `apt-get install kde-desktop`

Comment: package names for the desktop envs are mostly the same. apt-get and aptitude install also have the same result

Answer (score 1):

Xfce is a lightweight desktop environment for UNIX-like operating systems. It aims to be fast and low on system resources, while still being visually appealing and user friendly.

To install Xfce on debian 7 wheezy

```
# apt-get install xorg xfce4 xfce4-goodies thunar-archive-plugin synaptic gdebi wicd
```

To install extra XFCE packages

```
# apt-get install xdg-utils xfce4-power-manager xfce4-goodies htop bzip2 zip unzip unrar-free
```

There are more gui to choose from http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html